# Rounded corners not working for image button in IE

Tags: html, css, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I can`t get this rounded cornes work for image buttons in IE.
It's working in other browsers, like Mozilla, Chrome and Opera, but not IE11.

I have tried to get the rounded corners, with both CSS and ajaxcontroltoolkit:

```
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .RoundedElement {
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>


        CSS<br />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCSS" CssClass="RoundedElement" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Bilder/1034.jpg" />
                        <br />
        AjaxControlToolKit:<br />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAjax" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Bilder/1034.jpg" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="imgbtnAjax_RoundedCornersExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="imgbtnAjax_RoundedCornersExtender" Radius="15" TargetControlID="imgbtnAjax" />
                            <br />
        CSS<br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCSS" CssClass="RoundedElement" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <br />
        AjaxControlToolKit:<br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAjax" CssClass="RoundedElement" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="btnAjax_RoundedCornersExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="btnAjax_RoundedCornersExtender" Radius="15" TargetControlID="btnAjax" />


</div>
</form>
```

The regular buttons work in IE11. Both CSS and Ajax.

Comment: We'd need to see the output HTML...ASP isn't much use here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess that you are running IE11 in one of the compatibility modes for it to break something as simple as a border-radius.

Comment: This was exact case for me.. thanks this answer helped me